# Deploying EJB 2.0 in Jboss EAP 6.4

Tags: jboss, ejb, classcastexception

I am migrating my JBoss 4.3GA Enterprise application consisting of one Web module and one EJB module to JBoss 6.4 EAP.

I did all the changes that was specified in JBoss migration doc provided on their website.  [JBoss migration doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Migration_Guide/sect-EJB_2.x_Changes.html)

I was even able to successfully deploy my ear in the server but got the below error whenthe first ejb is called.

Servlet hibernateInit threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.adminserver.bll.SystemInformationBll$$$view42 cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object.

Any suggestion what may be wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by correcting the JNDI name in lookup binding in standalone.xml by replacing the local iterface to remote iterface.

This is exactly what i did..
Replace

```
 <lookup name="java:global/coname/ABCDBll" lookup="java:global/ABCDEnterpriseApp/EBCDEJBApp/ABCDBll!com.coname.bll.ABCDBllRemote"/>
```

with this

```
<lookup name="java:global/coname/ABCDBll" lookup="java:global/ABCDEnterpriseApp/EBCDEJBApp/ABCDBll!com.coname.bll.ABCDBllRemoteHome"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Looked up class and the local class loaded by different class loader so the type cast failed
- Check the application code and make sure that the correct JNDI name is used in order to lookup the EJBs.
- Check if the application has duplicate classes packaged in multiple modules/jars